# How to use a variable with a Null VALUE in IF EXISTS STATEMENT

Tags: t-sql

If i use a variable with my IF EXISTS STATEMENT i get the wrong result with null values.
If you look on the following source code. I get the result 'dont exist' although both variables
have the same value (null).

```
insert into test values (1,'hzii','uii','huioho')
insert into test values (2,'ahzdii',null,'ahsuioho')
insert into test values (3,'bhzii','buii','bhuioho')
insert into test values (4,'chzii','cuii','chuioho')

DECLARE @test varchar(255)
set @test = null

if exists (select id,test,test2,test3 from test where test='ahzdii' and test2=@test and test3='ahsuioho')
begin

    print 'exists'

end
else
    print 'dont exist'
```

I found a workaround by doing this:

```
if exists (select id,test,test2,test3 from test where test='ahzdii' and (test2=@test or (test2 is null and @test is null)) and test3='ahsuioho')
```

Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: No, if you want to compare a `NULL` value'd parameter to "equal" a `NULL` value'd column then `@Parameter IS NULL AND ColumnName IS NULL` is the correct syntax.

Comment: See solution below. You don't need to compare with NULL, just assign a default value when NULL, and compare to it.

Comment: select id,test,test2,test3 from test where test='ahzdii' and test2 is null and test3='ahsuioho' will give your desired answer @StefanK

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(255) = ''

    if (select count(*) from Test where test='ahzdii' and ISNULL(test2, '')=@test and test3='ahsuioho') > 0
            print 'exists'
        else
            print 'dont exist'  
    ;
```

Comment: Simply check param is equal or is null would be enough. IF exists  ( Select count (1) FROM TbName Where ...... ) is preferred in these cases and good for performance